# Differential form calculation

Tags: differential-forms

Below is a problem from Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*.  I'm not seeing how the calculation for $\omega_3$ is performed.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a change of coordinates from $(r,\phi)$ to $(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: I have.  I've used $T(a, b) = (a \cos b, a \sin b)$.  $T$ is the familiar polar coordinates transformation.  To find $\omega_3(\eta_1, \xi_1)$ at the point $(1, 1)$ I need to....this is where I get stuck.  The vectors $\eta_1$ and $\xi_1$ are given in rectangular coordinates.  Do I convert these to polar coordinates and find a point that gets mapped to $(1, 1)$ via $T$ or do I go in the reverse direction?

Comment: You can do both ways, the result should be the same.

Comment: Consider $\omega_3(\xi_1, \eta_1)$.  We have that $(1, 0)$ gets mapped to $\xi_1$ by $T$.  The point $(\sqrt{2}, \pi/4)$ maps to $\eta_1$.  We are evaluating $\omega_3$ at the point $(1, 1)$ and tangent vectors $\xi_1, \eta_1$. Thus shouldn't $rdr\wedge d\theta$ be $\sqrt{2} \cdot \frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: T is used to map points, $\xi_1$ is a vector so you must compute T's differential to map $\xi_1$.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Yes, that is the source of my confusion.  I was forgetting that $\xi_1$ and $\eta_1$ are in the tangent space and need to be transformed by the DT.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will denote $x_{1}=x$ and $x_{2}=y$.

Using the identities $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$ you have $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\phi=\tan^{-1}(\frac{y}{x})$.

Now compute $dr=\partial_{x}rdx+\partial_{y}rdy$ and $d\phi=\partial_{x}\phi dx+\partial_{y}\phi dy$.

You will obtain $\omega_{3}(x,y) =dx\wedge dy$.

Comment: Do you mean to have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ in front of the $dx\wedge dy$?

Comment: No, if you compute the derivatives and express de 2-form as $dx\wedge dy$ then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ cancel.

Comment: Sorry, I was just converting $dr\wedge d\theta$ to $dx \wedge dy$ and forgot that we had multiplication by $r$ in the original problem.